# How to use link to SVG file inside image element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I try to add my SVG on this way:

```
<svg>
    <image class="logo" src="facebook.svg"/>
</svg>
```

Why it doesn't work? The way to this SVG file is correct.
Of course, I could add my SVG with `img` or `background` and it would be easier. But I think it's option is the best, because I need to change the color of my SVG image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use SVG-file inside [`image` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) in SVG! But this tag does not have `src` attribute. This attribute is from HTML `img` tag.

Inside `image` tag you have to use [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href) attribute or also [`xlink:href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) attribute (but it is deprecated since SVG 2) for this purpose.

```html
<svg width="50" height="150">       
      <image href="https://developer.mozilla.org/static/platforms/mobile.d9737f9e22aa.svg" width="50"  height="150"/>
</svg>
```